# Splits the records based on row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to split the items based on range provided by input values @ExcludeFrom & @ExcludeTo.

below is my @itemrange table.

```
    Declare @ItemRange table
    (
        Id int primary key, 
        ItemId int,
        [FROM] int,
        [To] int
    )


    INSERT INTO @ItemRange
    VALUES  
    (1,1,1,10000000),
    (2,2,101,500),
    (3,2,600,700)


Declare @ExcludeFrom as int =500000 ,  @ExcludeTo as int =700000 , @ItemId as int =1
```

And Expected Result would be :  `( [to]= (@ExcludeFrom-1) and [From]= (@ExcludeTo+1)`

[image]

Note: Ranges difference are more than 10 millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try a calendar table approach here, where the calendar table contains the ranges you want to match:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS start, 499999 AS end UNION ALL
    SELECT 700001, NULL
)

SELECT
    t2.ItemId,
    t1.start,
    COALESCE(t1.[end], t2.[To]) AS [end]
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN ItemRange t2
    ON (t2.[From] <= t1.[end] OR t1.[end] IS NULL) AND t2.[To] >= t1.start
WHERE
    t2.ItemId = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: thanks...How can i get Cte .. ExcludeFrom & ExcludeTo are  dynamic value .. can u pls suggest how to get the CTE?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this.  My answer assumes that your ranges are already inside a table or CTE somewhere.  If they're not, then maybe you could write a proc which populates such a table or CTE.

Comment: Actually records exists table only ,,but only one record means [Itemid] [Start] [end]  i.e 1,500000,700000

Comment: Between my answer and the last almost identical question you asked, you already have two approaches here.