# Find Range in Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `@NumberRange`. It has a start and end number. I have to find out ranges are in sequence

```
Declare @NumberRange table
(
    Id int primary key, 
    ItemId int,
    [start] int,
    [end] int
)


INSERT INTO @NumberRange
VALUES  
(1,1,1,10),
(2,1,11,20),
(3,1,21,30),
(4,1,40,50),
(5,1,51,60),
(6,1,61,70),
(7,1,80,90),
(8,1,100,200)
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Note:  Result Column calculated from if any continuous numbers i.e 1 to 10 ,11-20,21-30 are continuous numbers. So result column updated as 1 and then 41-50 not continuous numbers (because previous row end with 30 next row start with 40) that is why result column will be 2 and it continuous..

In 4th end with 50 and 5 th start with 51 continuous then result would be 3 because I have differentiate with Result 1...

I have used `lead` functions and expected result not came,..please can someone help me get the result?

Workaround:

```
select  
    *,
    [Diff] = [Lead] - [end], 
    [Result] = Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ([Lead] - [end]) ORDER BY Id) 
from 
    (select 
         id, [start], [end], LEAD([start]) over (order by id) as [Lead] 
     from 
         @NumberRange) Z   
order by 
    id
```

Comment: Shouldn't you accept [answers to your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390541/splits-the-records-based-on-row) before asking a very similar one?

Comment: Why is `Id` 5 in result 3? It follows on from `Id` 4, so shouldn't it be 2 as well?

Comment: No if any break in contious number  then it should  be always previous+1..

Comment: But 50+1 = 51... Why is 10 and 11 not a break, but 50 and 51 is (and then 60 and 61 isn't again)? Your data doesn't make sense.

Comment: Pretty sure I have a solution here for you, but relies on your expected results being wrong. And if they are "right" then the logic is unclear, so I'll withhold until an explanation.

Comment: for ex: in row 3 end with 30 and in row 4 start with 40 so gap is 10 , 5th row there is no gap then also it should be increased and if any gap in next row it should be increased ..

Comment: So what si the logic here. Increase the value of `Result` when there is a gap and don't when there isn't, apart from ID 5, then increase it because *{unexplained logic goes here}*?

Answer (score 2):

Use `lag()` to determine where the groups start.  Then a cumulative sum to enumerate them:

```
select nr.*,
       sum(case when startr = prev_endr + 1  then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by itemid order by startr) as grp
from (select nr.*, lag(endr) over (partition by itemid order by startr) as prev_endr
      from numberrange nr
     ) nr;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=065092e47a8c9da9539ff9de6922ed4c) is a db<>fiddle.

This answer assumes that ids 4 and 5 are continuous, which makes sense based on the rest of the question.

Comment: This has `ID` 5 with a `result` of 2 though, Gordon. The OP is adamant, in the comments, it should be 3. No logic given as to why, mind.

Comment: sir  thanks  lot ..but 5th row Result should be 3 ..is it posible? because previous  numbers are not contious..

Comment: @Ljt you still haven't explain how 50 and 51 are ***not*** continuous. What integer number is between 50 and 51?

Comment: I think you've forgotten to supply us with the *real* picture here @Ljt . Without real explanations and expected results you aren't going to get an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result is not clear and the questions which are asked in the comments I have too, but I think what you want to do is something similar to

```
select  N1.*,case when N1.[end]+1=N2.[start] then 1 else 2 end Result from @NumberRange N1 inner join @NumberRange N2 on N1.Id=N2.Id-1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but i have differentiate id-1,2 with 4,5  thats y i dont need same result with 1